# Virtuoso Create SPARQL endpoint via ISQL Missing option

Tags: virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I am trying to create an endpoint to access `/sparql` endpoint using iSQL.
My current query is

```
DB.DBA.VHOST_DEFINE (
  vhost=>'test',
  lhost=>':4457',
  lpath=>'/sparql',
  ppath=>'/!sparql/',
  is_dav=>1,
  is_brws=>0,
  def_page=>'sparql.vsp',
  vsp_user=>'dba',
  ses_vars=>0,
  opts=>vector ('browse_sheet', ''),
  is_default_host=>1
);
```

This function is working perfect with one missing option `Map the logical path to a single page` and I don't know how to set it. I can only set it by webapp but not in this function.
Thank you

Comment: Also asked via [comment on github issue](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/604#issuecomment-416385414). I am researching, and expect to post answers here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*tl;dr: Include `'noinherit', 'yes'` in the `opts=>vector(...)` parameter, and set a `def_page` value, in the `DB.DBA.VHOST_DEFINE()` call.*

The Virtuoso Conductor (HTML-based Admin UI) includes an "Export" feature with regards to the configuration of a Virtual Domain and its associated Folders (WebDAV or Filesystem hosted).

Here's an example of the output for a folder mapped to "/test" for a particular Virtual Domain functioning as a Web Site (i.e., HTTP-access point for a collection of documents).

With Single-Page check-box hatched:

```
DB.DBA.VHOST_REMOVE (
     lhost=>'*ini*',
     vhost=>'*ini*',
     lpath=>'/test'
);

DB.DBA.VHOST_DEFINE (
     lhost=>'*ini*',
     vhost=>'*ini*',
     lpath=>'/test',
     ppath=>'/DAV/',
     is_dav=>1,
     is_brws=>0,
     def_page=>'test.vsp',
     vsp_user=>'dba',
     ses_vars=>0,
     opts=>vector ('browse_sheet', '', 'noinherit', 'yes'),
     is_default_host=>0
);
```

With checkbox unhatched:

```
DB.DBA.VHOST_REMOVE (
     lhost=>'*ini*',
     vhost=>'*ini*',
     lpath=>'/test'
);

DB.DBA.VHOST_DEFINE (
     lhost=>'*ini*',
     vhost=>'*ini*',
     lpath=>'/test',
     ppath=>'/DAV/',
     is_dav=>1,
     is_brws=>0,
     def_page=>'test.vsp',
     vsp_user=>'dba',
     ses_vars=>0,
     opts=>vector ('browse_sheet', ''),
     is_default_host=>0
);
```

Note line **`opts=>vector ('browse_sheet', '', 'noinherit', 'yes')`** .